# angularjs hide show panals and classes

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to hide and show panels while on click using ng-click. I know this is not a good way but I don't have any logic how to handle because I'm new in angularjs
can you please answer I hope you understand my question what i want to ask

```
// about panel
    $scope.activePanelAbout = function() {
    $scope.infoPanel = false;
    $scope.aboutPanel = true;
    $scope.expPanel = false;
    $scope.eduPanel = false;
    $scope.skillPanel = false;
    $scope.certiPanel = false;
    $scope.refPanel = false;
  }
  // experience panel
    $scope.activePanelExp = function() {
    $scope.infoPanel = false;
    $scope.aboutPanel = false;
    $scope.expPanel = true;
    $scope.eduPanel = false;
    $scope.skillPanel = false;
    $scope.certiPanel = false;
    $scope.refPanel = false;
  }
  // education panel
    $scope.activePanelEdu = function() {
    $scope.infoPanel = false;
    $scope.aboutPanel = false;
    $scope.expPanel = false;
    $scope.eduPanel = true;
    $scope.skillPanel = false;
    $scope.certiPanel = false;
    $scope.refPanel = false;
  }
  // skill panel
    $scope.activePanelSkill = function() {
    $scope.infoPanel = false;
    $scope.aboutPanel = false;
    $scope.expPanel = false;
    $scope.eduPanel = false;
    $scope.skillPanel = true;
    $scope.certiPanel = false;
    $scope.refPanel = false;
  }
```

Comment: why hiding panels using `ng-click` would not be a "good way"? NOTE: you should post you html too, and precise your question, is your code working or not? do you ask for a correction, or suggestions for another way?

Comment: because there are multiple panels that we need to show/hide onclick

Comment: yes code is working but i think this is not a good way is there another way like in Jquery we use this keyword

Comment: I suppose you have things like `ng-hide="ctrl.infoPanel"` in your view? This doesn't look bad to me, this respects the angular way of doing things, by separating the logic (in the controller) from the display (in the view). It would have seemed worse to me if you had tried to interact directly with your view from your controller, or worse, inline logic inside the `ng-click`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of repetition, so you can try to **reset** them all in a common function to `false`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  // reset
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.infoPanel = false;
    $scope.aboutPanel = false;
    $scope.expPanel = false;
    $scope.eduPanel = false;
    $scope.skillPanel = false;
    $scope.certiPanel = false;
    $scope.refPanel = false;
  }
  $scope.reset(); // initialise
  // about panel
  $scope.activePanelAbout = function() {
    $scope.aboutPanel = true;
  }
  // experience panel
  $scope.activePanelExp = function() {
    $scope.expPanel = true;
  }
  // education panel
  $scope.activePanelEdu = function() {
    $scope.eduPanel = true;
  }
  // skill panel
  $scope.activePanelSkill = function() {
    $scope.skillPanel = true;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <button ng-click="reset()">X</button>
  <button ng-click="reset();activePanelAbout()">About</button>
  <button ng-click="reset();activePanelExp()">Experience</button>
  <button ng-click="reset();activePanelEdu()">Education</button>
  <button ng-click="reset();activePanelSkill()">Skill</button>

  <br>aboutPanel {{aboutPanel}}
  <br>activePanelExp {{expPanel}}
  <br>activePanelEdu {{eduPanel}}
  <br>activePanelSkill {{skillPanel}}

</div>
```

Also depends on which panels you want, you can use `ui-bootstrap`'s accordion to display your data in a simpler way:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.panels = [{
      panel: "infoPanel",
      title: 'Info',
      content: 'Information Panel'
    },
    {
      panel: "aboutPanel",
      title: 'About',
      content: 'About Panel'
    },
    {
      panel: "expPanel",
      title: 'Experience',
      content: 'Experience Panel'
    },
    {
      panel: "eduPanel",
      title: 'Education',
      content: 'Education Panel'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <uib-accordion close-others="true">
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{panel.title}}" ng-repeat="panel in panels">
      {{panel.content}}
    </div>
  </uib-accordion>

</div>
```